# How to count the words and numbers in textarea using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I have problem on regular expression, its like i am trying to count the number of word in text area but i am not getting desired output. The main problem is, that it does not count the numbers for example "Hello world 123" it counts only 2. and for "123" it does not count at all. my regular expression is`response.trim().replace(/\b[\s,-:;'"_]*\b/gi, ' ').split(' ');`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve.  If it's just to count the chars in the field you can use `document.getElementById('your_id').value.length`

Comment: Is `php` a necessary tag here? Do you need the answer to be with JavaScript?

Comment: @MichaelRushton yes you can

Comment: Yes I can? You mean I can give an answer in PHP?

Comment: I mean you can answer either way

Comment: OK, then a simple PHP answer is below.

Comment: yeah but now i want  escape the special characters, i mean it should not be counted

Comment: So what characters should be counted? Just letters and numbers? If so, see the addition to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `/\b|\d+/gi` to search for word boundaries *or* numbers, then count the number of elements in the array.

```
var array = response.trim().match(/\b|\d+/gi);
var count = array.length;
```

Comment: That worked but i want to remove the special characters such as , : ? and all, i don't want them to be counted.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly i want to escape the special characters, such as - , . ?

Answer (score 0):

As you've tagged this with `php` I assume a `PHP` answer is acceptable, in which case you don't need a regular expression. You can just use [`str_word_count`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php):

```
echo str_word_count("Hello world 123!", 0, '0..9'); // 3
```

Notice the third parameter which allows you to specify additional characters which make up a word. As a default, numbers are not included, hence the addition here.

Alternatively you can use [`preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
preg_match_all('/\b[a-z\d]+\b/i', $string);
```

This will only count letters and numbers as word-characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is almost perfect, but there are two problems:

1. replace "at least one" occurrence of word separator characters (`+`) instead of any (`*`)
2. you have a `,-;` character range in your character class (`[...]`), which unfortunately include all numbers. When you want to match `-` (dash) put it always at the beginning of the character class!

So the corrected regular expression: `/\b[-\s,:;'"_]+\b/gi`

**Edit:** If you need to match every non-alphanumeric character, the use `[\W_]`

Comment: sorry sir it not working. it still counts the , . / ? (special characters)

Comment: @niku you're right, I took your solution as a starting point, but added a non-alpahnumeric matching pattern at the end of my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
array = response.trim().match(/\w+/g);
count = array.length;
```

In your array only the words (alphanumerical strings) will be stored.

For the record, `\w` is short for `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, which means it won't catch correctly words with special characters, like `journée`, but it will return 6 for `I'd like 1 cup...plz!`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this demo.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SujithPS/9nqLL/3/)**

You can use : `response.replace(/['?:_!'"@#$&%\^*()\\\/.-]/g,"").split(/[ \n\r]/);`

Comment: @SujithPS  i want to escape the special characters.

Comment: What if someone wants to separate two numbers like this: `1~10`? In my opinion it is safer, simpler and quicker to positively match your words than trying to erase everything that's not part of a word (that is, if you're aiming at the `[a-zA-Z0-1]` range)